# How to make a different title for each slide in the same Beamer frame

Tags: beamer

```
\documentclass[compress,red]{beamer}
% \usepackage{etex}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Warsaw}

% \usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}%les accents pour mac
% \usepackage{subfigure}
% \usepackage{multicol}
% \usepackage{animate}
% \usepackage{movie15}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% \usepackage{epsfig}
% \usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage[all,knot]{xy}
% \xyoption{arc}
% \usepackage{url}
% \usepackage{array,ragged2e}
% \usepackage{multimedia}
% \usepackage{hyperref}
% \usepackage{setspace}
% \usepackage{multirow} 
\begin{document}
% \section
\frame{\frametitle{Titre de la fenetre}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item point1
    \item point2
    \item point3
    \item point4
    \item point5
  \end{itemize}

  \only<1>{
    \begin{equation}
      a+b=c
    \end{equation}
  }
  \only<2>{
    \begin{equation}
      a+b=c
    \end{equation}
  }
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Looks like you're asking a similar question in another post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144920/title-for-each-slide-in-the-same-frame-on-beamer-latex. Can you merge the two questions into one? For example, you can copy the other question into this one and delete that question.

Comment: @KevinC excuse, I am deleting this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144920/title-for-each-slide-in-the-same-frame-on-beamer-latex

Comment: By the way, there is no need to load packages `hyperref` and `url`, because as far as I know, you'd only need one of these two packages, and Beamer automatically loads `hyperref`.

Comment: @KevinC, please, considering the example above, it is possible to use shrink with the \only?

Comment: What do you mean by "shrink"?

Comment: @KevinC, it is a frame option. It is used in case of slide contents debord. it is like allowframebreaks but it does not create an other slide to fix the deborder problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11500/discussion-between-kevin-c-and-phdstudent)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\only` on `\frametitle` to get different titles on different slides

### Code

```
\documentclass[compress,red]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}

\frame{
  \only<1>{\frametitle{Titre de la fenetre}}
  \only<2>{\frametitle{Another Title}}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item point1
    \item point2
    \item point3
    \item point4
    \item point5
  \end{itemize}
        
  \only<1>{
    \begin{equation}
      a+b=c
    \end{equation}
  }
  \only<2>{
    \begin{equation}
      a+b=c
    \end{equation}
  }
}
\end{document}
```